# Maplibre GL JS - animating canvas size

Tags: javascript, css, maplibre-gl

I can't find a solution for animating the canvas size of a `maplibregl` map where the map is preloaded in the hidden area. I want to bring the map to fullscreen and animate this resizing. When animating the height/width, the container gets smoothly larger, but the map doesn't. I can only resize the map when calling `map.resize()`, but not animate it. I tried with CSS clipping but this is not a good choice. Is there a possibility to get this to work?